# MySQL ERROR 1470 (HY000) string %s is too long for host name

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I need to update the Super privileges for an account not on localhost in order to turn of binary logging. When I do try to grant the privileges:

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%s' WITH GRANT OPTION;

It says that the host string %s is more than 60 characters (it is 74 characters).
All forums I've seen for this problem seem to revolve around incorrect quotation marks or using `` instead of quotation marks for the host name, but that hasn't worked for me.

Is there any way in which I update the super setting in another manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For host name that is too long, I would prefer using corresponded IP address instead.

Ip resolution is essential for the `grant` operation to execute as a sql statement, even if a host name is passed as argument in sql, it is to be underlying converted to address first, which could be done independently by `nslookup/dig/host`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the `''`.  i.e. From...

```
CREATE USER 'tcread@192.168.12.123' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

ERROR 1470 (HY000): String 'tcread@192.168.50.115' is too long for user name (should be no longer than 16)
```

To...

```
CREATE USER tcread@192.168.12.123 IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I guess the `@` need out of the `''`.  :)

Comment: Different problem.